# What is the topology of uniform convergence in this case of $P=P(x_{0},M)$ of all paths in $M$ starting at $x_{0}$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory

The following definition I found it in a text on Lie groups:

> Let $M$ be a connected smooth manifold and $x_{0}\in M$. A  *path in  $M$ starting at $x_{0}$* is a continuous curve $\gamma :[0,1]\longrightarrow M$ such that $\gamma (0)=x_{0}$. The space  $P=P(x_{0},M)$ of all paths in $M$ starting at $x_{0}$, will be provided with the **topology of uniform convergence**.

**My Question:**

What is the ***topology of uniform convergence*** in this case?

I know it's this topology in the case where  M is a metric space, but in this case where M is a manifold I can not say the same.

Comment: A manifold generally is a metric space (provided it's required to be paracompact, which is almost always assumed)

Comment: Since $[0,1]$ is compact, the topology of uniform convergence coincides with the compact-open topology, so it in fact only depends on the topology of $M$.